# LibreOffice Writer How to change height of tels line

Tags: windows

I am using most updated version of LibreOffice Writer on Del WIN 10 laptop.  I want to set/change the text line WIDTH, also sometimes called the line height ( not the line to line spacing). For reference I use Ariel 12 point font.

I have been unable to find instructions for Writer .

Answer (score 0):

Here's the help article on [Setting Indents, Margins, and Columns](https://help.libreoffice.org/latest/en-US/text/shared/02/13020000.html).
Alternatively you could try [Inserting Tables](https://help.libreoffice.org/latest/en-US/text/swriter/guide/table_insert.html) and size them separately from the rest of the document.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).